# Issue with parsing String to Unsigned in Rust language

Tags: parsing, rust

This is the code I have:

```
fn main() {
  use std::io::stdin;
  let mut s=String::new();
  stdin().read_line(&mut s).expect("Wrong input");
  let n = s.parse::<u32>();
  println!("Try: {:?}", n);
}
```

I get no error while compiling, but it prints this in running time:

`Err(ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit })`

Comment: Not sure but....did you check if you have a trailing `\n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a trailing `\n` in your string, use [`String::trim_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim_end):

```rust
fn main() {
  let n = "10\n".trim_end().parse::<u32>();
  println!("Try: {:?}", n);
}
```

From `BufRead::read_line` [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line):

> This function will read bytes from the underlying stream until the
> newline delimiter (the 0xA byte) or EOF is found. Once found, all
> bytes up to, and including, the delimiter (if found) will be appended
> to buf.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is fixed now

Comment: @Interity You're supposed to accept the answers when they're good and solve your problem